# Out of Google storage space

Tags: google-chrome

I recently received notice that I'm running out of Google storage space. I purged as much as I could and still got the error. It said I was nearing 10 GB. I took the plunge and purchased the 100 GB data package. Now I'm told I am at that limit as well. I know I do NOT have 100 GB of data stored in Google. Maybe there is a duplication issue or an error on my part in moving things, but the problem is I can't find where the stored data is to purge. Please help. I am NOT a programmer.

Thank you,

Mark Cornelius

Comment: This site is for programming questions. See [webapps.se] instead

Answer (score -1):

You can view what is using your google space here: https://drive.google.com/u/0/settings/storage?hl=en

You may also have some hidden app data in Drive, heres how to delete it:

Click Settings
On the left, click Manage Apps.

Select Options of that app.

Select Delete hidden app data.

Please mark as answer if this helped :)